# Пустой список хотя я его заполнял

Tags: python, функции, list

У меня есть список `star_areas`, который по началу пустой. Я хотел его заполнить в функции.

Вот функция:

```
def houses(x, y):
    global star_areas
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.down()
    h, w = randrange(300, 501, 60), randrange(200, 401, 60)
    
    lst = ('gray', 'Burlywood')
    house(x, y, h, w, choice(lst))
    star_areas.append((x, x + w, h))
    
    for _ in range(5):
    x += w + 1
    star_areas.append((x, x + w, h))
    
    h, w = randrange(300, 501, 60), randrange(200, 401, 60) #randrange(500, 701, 60), randrange(200, 401, 60)
    
    house(x, y, h, w, choice(lst))
```

Вроде она заполняется, но когда я хочу вывести ее содержимое вне функции, ничего не выводится. Но если запринтить список в функции, то все нормально выводится.

Вот весь код:

````
from random import *
star_areas = []
def house(x, y, height, width, color):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.fillcolor(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(height)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(width)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(height)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.end_fill()
    for i in range(x + 10, x + width - 10, 40):
        for j in range(y + 10, y + height - 10, 40):
            window(i, j, 20, randint(0, 1))
def window(x, y, side, islight_on):
    turtle.fillcolor(('black', 'yellow')[islight_on])
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.begin_fill()
    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.forward(side)
        turtle.left(90)
    turtle.end_fill()
 #turtle.forward(side / 2)
 #turtle.left(90)
 #turtle.forward(side)
 #turtle.up()
    #turtle.goto(x, y)
 #turtle.right(90)
 #turtle.down()
def houses(x, y):
    global star_areas
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.down()
    h, w = randrange(300, 501, 60), randrange(200, 401, 60)
    lst = ('gray', 'Burlywood')
    house(x, y, h, w, choice(lst))
    star_areas.append((x, x + w, h))
    for _ in range(5):
        x += w + 1
        star_areas.append((x, x + w, h))
        h, w = randrange(300, 501, 60), randrange(200, 401, 60) #randrange(500, 701, 60), randrange(200, 401, 60)
        house(x, y, h, w, choice(lst))
#print(star_areas)
def star(x, y, size):
     turtle.up()
     turtle.goto(x, y)
     turtle.down()
     turtle.fillcolor('yellow')
     turtle.begin_fill()
     for _ in range(4):
         turtle.forward(size)
         turtle.left(90)
     turtle.forward(0)
     turtle.end_fill()
xcors = []
ycors = []
def stars():
  #global xcors, ycors, star_areas
  for area in star_areas:
      a, b, c = area
      while len(xcors) != 10:
          x, y = randrange(a, b - 15), randrange(c + 10, 1000)
          while checking(x, y) != True:
              x, y = randrange(a, b - 15), randrange(c, 550)
          xcors.append(x)
          ycors.append(y)
          star(x, y, randint(13, 15))
def checking(x, y):
    global xcors, ycors
    if x in xcors or y in ycors:
        return False
    else:
        return True```
````

Comment: исправьте форматирование кода. сейчас не понятно "что как и где"

Comment: Покажите остальной код. Возможно, вы там где-то этот список очищаете.

Comment: Но я принтил содержимое списка `star_areas` сразу после функции.

Comment: а где выполнение функций? есть только их объявление.

Comment: только что заметил, что выводил содержимое до выполнения функции, спасибо.